# What were Jesus' post-resurrection teachings about the Father?

Tags: jesus, father

> These things have I spoken unto you in proverbs: but the time cometh, when I shall no more speak unto you in proverbs, but I shall shew you **plainly of the Father**. John 16:25 KJV

Comment: What makes you think they had to be post resurrection? Are the handing over, the trial, the suffering, the death upon the cross, three days in the earth, and the resurrection not also manifestations of the Father?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the most significant post-resurrection teachings of Jesus about the Father is found in John 20.

> Jesus saith unto her, Touch me not; for I am not yet ascended to my
> Father: but go to my brethren, and say unto them, I ascend unto my
> Father, and your Father; and to my God, and your God. (John 20:17,
> KJV)

A few verses later, Jesus repeats another truth about the Father that he had spoken on many occasions prior to his death.

> Then said Jesus to them again, Peace be unto you: as my Father hath
> sent me, even so send I you. (John 20:21, KJV)

Jesus had spoken, during his lifetime, about God being his Father.

> Therefore the Jews sought the more to kill him, because he not only
> had broken the sabbath, but **said also that God was his Father,** making
> himself equal with God.  (John 5:18, KJV)

He had also said that his Father was "the only true God."

> <sup>1</sup> These words spake Jesus, and lifted up his eyes to
> heaven, and said, **Father,** the hour is come; glorify thy Son, that
> thy Son also may glorify thee: <sup>2</sup> As thou hast given him
> power over all flesh, that he should give eternal life to as many as
> thou hast given him. <sup>3</sup> And this is life eternal, that they
> might know **thee the only true God,** and Jesus Christ, whom thou
> hast sent. (John 17:1-3, KJV)

And Jesus had said many times that the Father had sent him.

> And **the Father himself, which hath sent me,** hath borne witness of
> me. Ye have neither heard his voice at any time, nor seen his shape.
> (John 5:37, KJV)
>
> For I have not spoken of myself; but **the Father which sent me,** he
> gave me a commandment, what I should say, and what I should speak.
> (John 12:49, KJV)

(See also John 5:23,30,36; 6:39,44,57; 8:16,18,29,42, etc.--Jesus says the Father had sent him at least 16 times during his lifetime, which is why John 20:21 says "Then said Jesus to them **again,** ....")

Essentially, after his resurrection, Jesus is teaching that nothing has changed.  The Father is still his God and our God.  And Jesus himself is still the one whom the Father had sent.

Comment: You had the card up your sleeve...